# angularjs, maximage 2 and cycle plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I wrote the following directive which allows me to use maximgae plugin with angular:

```
directives.directive('maximage', [
function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            scope.$on('LastElem', function(event) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        $(element).maximage({,
                            cycleOptions: {
                                fx: 'fade',
                                speed: 800,
                                timeout: 4000,
                                end: function() {
                                    alert('The slideshow has ended.');
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });

            });
        }
    }
}
]);
```

the problem is that the end callback function is not executed when the slide ends.

This problem happens also when I try to define cycle's options outside angular's scope with:

```
$.fn.cycle.defaults
```

The other options like timeout are loaded without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: like mentioned in the documentation nowrap or autostop options are required to trigger the 'end' callback.

Answer (score 0):

i got both defined and still 'end' is not being called ;S

```
    $('#idol-boxes').cycle({
        timeout: 0,
        autostop: true,
        nowrap: true,
        next: '#idol-boxes',
        speed: 'fast',
        end: function () {
            alert('The slideshow has ended.');
        }
    });
```